# Web Architecture - Where to put uploaded binary data

Tags: design-patterns, web, architecture

Generally when developing websites I like to keep as much as possible off of the web server. I try and store configuration details, session data and the like in a database back end. This then enables me to easily re-build the web server if required or theoretically add in more web servers if needed.

The one issue I have is when the clients upload image data or binary files. I tend to store these on the web server raw rather than putting them in the database. The problem with this though is that I then need to backup this data from the web server, which I don't really like.

I would prefer to have the web server just serve data, but not store it. I've looked at options like FTPing the files onto another group of web servers which just act as content delivery servers (no scripting or processing on them) or putting the clients data into a blob on the database. Another option I've thought about would be putting the files onto a specific file server, as you would on a LAN then mounting the share from the file server on the web server and having the webserver deliver it directly. I've even considered putting it into a Hadoop style HDFS distributed filesystem and then having the webservers pull it from there but none of these really seem quite right.

Anyhow to the question, what is generally considered best practice when storing client provided binary data such as images or documents?

I'd prefer a generic web architecture type response / approach rather then just the way one specific language may encourage or promote a certain solution. However if you can compare and contrast approaches promoted by a number of different languages / libraries then that would be very interesting to know about also.

Comment: Adding those files in your database isn't an option?

Comment: It is an option, in fact they are all possible. It's more a case of which is considered "good practice" and which are considered "bad practice" from a website design perspective. Clearly each comes with different factors to consider such as cost, ease of development, scalability etc.

Comment: Database or the cloud (amazon s3), favouring the latter

Comment: if (careAboutDataIntegrity) useDatabase(); else useS3();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to the people that did add to this question, however I eventually found what I was looking for over on serverfault by a member called [womble](https://serverfault.com/users/1375/womble).

Here is a link to their answer in case you find this question in the future:

https://serverfault.com/questions/297244/moving-away-from-nfs

This also links to another really helpful post on the same topic:

https://serverfault.com/questions/286910/setting-up-a-rails-2-3-x-app-on-ec2-for-easy-scalability

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by MikeSW in comments above, I would recommend to use [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3), which will act as a centralized and reliable storage of binaries, accessible from all your web servers. However, keep in mind their ["consistency model"](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#What_data_consistency_model_does_Amazon_S3_employ)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however this isn't so much an architectural solution as a product one. S3 would work very well on the internet, but what about an Intranet where the data must be kept private. Cyphering the uploads before depositing into S3 isn't really ideal. I really was looking for an architectural solution, however what I guess seems to be the consensus so far is that the data is places into a "database" off of the web server. This could be S3 or a closed private cloud like DB such as CloudStack, Nimbula, Riak, Eucalyptus etc.